# Show information only once in footnotes

Tags: biblatex

I am using `citestyle=authortitle-ibid`, but I have to make it work according to these rules:

1. The first time a reference is made, there should be all the information in the footnote (including publisher, author, editor, containing book, year etc.).
2. The second time the same reference is used, even on another page, the footnote should contain author, year and page, unless the information is ambigious without the title. In the latter case, the title should be contained as well.

I am wondering how one could achieve this. Personally, I think putting all the information in footnotes is a bad idea, however, I was told to do so.

Comment: In which cases are the informations ambiguous?

Comment: In other words, you want to combine the `authortitle` style with an `authordate` style?  Normally, when the year alone doesn't disambiguate, you add a letter. Smith 2001a vs Smith 2001b vs Smith 2002 --- no one is going to be confused as to which is which.  When you use titles, you disambiguate via the `shorttitle` field, which is what gets printed in subsequent citations.

Comment: Also when John Smith published something in 2000, and Robert Smith published something in 2000, then you usually want to have J. Smith 2000 vs R. Smith 2000: Smith 2000 + title won't (directly) tell you whether John or Robert was the author...

Comment: @jon As far as I know, I'll have to use the whole name (or at least last name + initial) anyway. I don't like this style, but my teacher enforces it for some reason.

Comment: Well many teachers, especially those who type out all their own references by hand, can have odd preferences.  Just to be clear: in the subsequent references where the title is necessary, the *full* title must be used, or the `shorttile` field?

Comment: @musicman If autor and year do not uniquely identify a bibliography item.

Comment: @jon Good question. Will this affect which solution is possible?

Comment: No, but it affects the answer.  The normal(?) behaviour would be to use a shorttitle in subsequent citations *if* it is available in the `.bib` entry (thus mimicking normal authortitle conventions like Chicago); but the requirements you were given do not qualify as normal...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14552/discussion-between-just-kidding-and-jon)

Comment: I won't be able to look at this in detail until (maybe) this evening, unfortunately.  But I thought it useful to get all the requirements stated explicitly (bibliographies/citations are finicky things) in case someone else wanted to provide a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer

My original answer used `chicago`, because it's a highly developed style which I thought came close to what was wanted. However, a comment in response indicated that the questioner has developed his/her own custom `.bbx` style based on `authortitle-ibid`, and I think there are likely to be conflicts there.

Frankly, I don't think `authortitle-ibid` is the place to start: a key feature of the style you want is (a) *full* citations at first and (b) *short* citations on subsequent use. The standard style that comes close to this is `verbose-ibid`, and that is probably the right place to start. It's still *more likely* to be compatible with your custom adjustments, since it won't be far from `authortitle-ibid` as far as full citations is concerned, and it will certainly be closer than `chicago`. If you start from `authortitle` you are going to have to recreate all the structure for full citations and so forth that is already present in `verbose`, which is pointless.

Within the `verbose-ibid` style, the typesetting of shortened citations is handled by the `bibmacro` `cite:short`, and so we redefine that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author1,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  title     = {First Work},
  date      = {2010},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{author2,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  title     = {Second Work},
  date      = {2010},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{author3,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  title     = {Third Work},
  date      = {2011},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\setlength{\textheight}{2in}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,labeldate=true]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \iffieldundef{extrayear}%
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
     \mkbibparens{\printdatelabel}}}
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
     \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{\mkbibparens{\printdatelabel}}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

We use \texttt{verbose-ibid} as our style, setting \texttt{labeldate}
true so as to have a hook to decide if we have multiple works by the
same author(s) in the same year.

We revise the \texttt{cite:short} macro. On the first occasion
something is printed, we will have full citations.\footcite{author1,
  author2, author3} On subsequent occasions they will be shortened,
with titles added only if necessary for
disambiguation.\footcite{author1, author2, author3}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image: Results]

### Original Answer

The effect you want is nearly the default with the `biblatex-chicago` style, with the `notes` option: it is loaded (unusually) as a free-standing package not a style, but it makes full use of `biblatex`. The documentation is extensive.

Indeed, I first thought that this just did what you want: but I was reading too quickly -- the default is to have an author/title style on subsequent citations, not the mixture of author/year and title you suggest. That can, however, be fairly easily accomplished by redefining one `bibmacro`: we also need to add the `labeldate` option, not because we add any additional labels this way, but because it's a handy way of getting `biber` to tell us if there is more than one relevant citation in a given year. The basic technique could, I think, be easily adapted to the standard styles.

A brief example follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title  = {First Work},
  date   = {2010},
}
@book{author2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title  = {Second Work},
  date   = {2010},
}
@book{author3,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title  = {Third Work},
  date   = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,labeldate=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
    {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
      \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%\printnames{labelname}%
        \isdot\classicpunct}}}%
  \iffieldundef{extrayear}% Is the reference unique?
    {\setunit*{\addspace}}% No: change punctuation from comma to space ready for year
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}% Yes: print the title
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \mkbibparens{\printdatelabel}}}% We want the date label not the title
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \mkbibparens{\printdatelabel}}}% We want the date label not the title
}%:\thefield{entrytype}?
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

With \texttt{biblatex-chicago} with the \texttt{notes} option, the
default is for citation to appear in footnotes, with a full citation
on the first occasion and an abbreviated citation on subsequent occasions. 

So the first citation is full,\footcite{author1} an immediately
following citation will use \emph{ibid}\footcite[Thus:][]{author1},
(unless \texttt{ibidtracker} is set false) but otherwise later
citations will be abbreviated.

We do, however, have to make minor modifications to one macro, because
by default the package assumes author/title citations, but we have to
provide author/year citations, with the date printed only if there is
more than one work in the relevant year. We thus get all our full
citations out,\footcite{author1, author2, author3} and then
demonstrate that happening.\footcite{author1, author2, author3}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the modifications]

Comment: I don't think this is quite true:  the point is that the year is always included in the subsequent citations, and, when that is not enough, *then* the title is added as well in order to disambiguate.  (The year only partially disambiguates on its own --- that's what makes it weird!)

Comment: @jon You are right: I read too quickly.

Comment: @PaulStanley This looks great, can't wait to try it! I already wrote a custom bbx file for my bibliography, can I still use it with the `biblatex-chicago` package?

Comment: Well, I doubt a custom `bbx` file will work smoothly with `chicago`; but if you look at the `bibmacro` above, I doubt you will have much difficulty in converting it to your package. The useful "trick" is the use of extrayear to do your disambiguation, and that should be adaptable to the standard package. But if you are trying to customize towards this result, it would be easier to start with `verbose-ibid` anyway, since that gets *closer* to what you want ....

Comment: @just.kidding I have updated my answer to use the same technique but with a standard style, which you will probably find easier to work with.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! I'd accept this answer twice if I could. Thank you!

Comment: Could you have a look at my [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178862/)?