# Make author names bold in bibliography only

Tags: biblatex, bold

I am using an adaption of the `verbose-ibid` citestyle (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178555/51451)) and a custom bbx file based on `authoryear`. One of the things it changes is that it makes the author names appear bold. The only problem is that the `verbose-ibid` style seems to use the same macro and the bold names therefore appear in footcites as well.

Here is the relevant part of the bbx:

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false,firstinits=true}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \textbf{\printnames{author}}% THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addspace}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

How can I apply `textbf` in the bibliography ony, not touching citations and footnotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most `biblatex` styles use the name format `sortname` to print the author names in the bibliography, so we can redefine that format.

In particular `sortname` is the name format used for the `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-based bibliography styles (including the `verbose` family). If you want a similar effect for `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles you should redefine the name formats `author`, `editor` and `translator` directly.

First we define a new format: `first-last-bold`, it is based on `first-last`, but with an added `\mkbibbold{`

```
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

similarly one could have

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

or

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

then we tell `biblatex` to use the new format

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-bold}
```

This last step might have to be

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family-bold}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{given-family-bold}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{given-family-bold}
```

with some styles.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-bold}

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero,wilde,baez/article,knuth:ct,aristotle:physics}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The answer has been updated to conform with the new name format in version 3.3, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: This doesn't work for more recent versions of biblatex: see [this answer by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/82389)

Comment: @DavidRobertson Indeed this is a common problem for answers about the name format. Are you interested in an updated answer or are you OK with the hint in Ulrike's answer?

Comment: I think I've got the hang of it; I'll try to post it as an answer later today. Thanks for the offer though!

Comment: The full code of this style can be please. I could not get this performance.

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad The last code block (titled MWE) is a fully compilable example document that contains *all* the required code to get the output shown below. (In fact I will edit the answer soon since there is a much easier solution with newer versions of `biblatex`.) But the code requires `biblatex` and Biber. If you use BibTeX it may not be compatible with what you have so far.

Comment: @moewe I ask the question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561978/make-author-names-bold-in-bibliography?noredirect=1#comment1416883_561978, that should be with run by xlatex. Can you please help?

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad As I suspected you are using (classical) BibTeX and not `biblatex` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 for a short explanation of what BibTeX and `biblatex` are). This solution is not compatible with your approach so far. And I'm afraid to say getting this done is a bit tricky with BibTeX (since it uses quite an arcane programming language). Off the top of my head I can't offer you a BibTeX solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the hook `\AtBeginBibliography`:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to use `\mkbibbold` instead of `\tetxbf`.

Comment: @moewe: Indeed. It's done.

Comment: One draw-back of this solution is though that all names in the bibliography will be printed in bold, even editors and translators. Also the "and" between author names is not printed in bold.

Comment: @moewe Is there any way to prevent that? If not, I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: @just.kidding It will be hard to avoid the first shortcoming I mentioned above without redefining (potentially quite a lot of) other commands. The second issue (noon bold and) can probably be dealt with, even though this will cause all "and"s to be bold (bringing you back to issue #1).

Comment: Comment in passing: In my case, with ``beamer``, I had to squeeze this inside a ``makeatletter``  and ``makeatother`` job. The ``AtBeginBibliography`` wasn't working. Of all the answers, this is the only one that worked for me!

Comment: ``\mkbibnamelast`` has become ``\mkbibnamefamily``, apparently.

Comment: @PatrickT And `\mkbibnamefirst` has become `\mkbibnamegiven`; `\mkbibnameaffix` is `\mkbibnamesuffix` now. Note that this solution bolds all names (for example also editors of `@incollection`s) which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Thanks moewe. Do you have a solution to bold only the authors of the articles and not the authors of the collection? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT Authors or editors? Did you try my solution above? It bolds only the "primary" names associated with the work (the first name in the bibliography entry, usually the `author`, for some the `editor`). It should work for most standard styles, but if you use APA style that probably won't work. In that case I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I was indeed using the apa style. Well let me try it out with some other style and see if I can get something like what I was looking for (I'm not that fussy). May need a few days to get back to this. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT In general I would only use `biblatex-apa` if I have to follow the APA style - or a derived style with *tiny* modifications. Usually the standard styles are much easier to customise and modify because `biblatex-apa` has to work hard to implement the APA guidelines (the same goes for a specialist styles, `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-mla`, ...). `style=authoryear` or its derived styles might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the `\textbf`-command by using the xpatch-package.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

Then you have to write before the `\printbibliography`:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{\printnames{author}}{\textbf{\printnames{author}}}{}{}
```

which will replace the command.

(untested)

Comment: I think you mixed up the order of the arguments, it ought to be `\xpatchbibmacro{author}{\printnames{author}}{\textbf{\printnames{author}}}{}{}`. Also note that this will only work with styles that use the original `author` macro and will not set `editor`s of `@collections` in bold even though they are displayed like `author`s in the bibliography. I would suggest you use `\mkbibbold` instead of `\textbf`.

Comment: you are right, i've read it wrong. and this of course only work for the wanted `author`-bibmacro.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178877/82389) that's updated to work with [biblatex versions 3.3+](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/82389). I'm not an expert with biblatex at all, but wanted to write down what what I did to update the name format.

On my machine at work, the system-wide installation of biblatex is version 2.8a. Section 4.4.2 of the documentation explains that
`\DeclareNameFormat` takes an three arguments.
Within the third argument, `#1` through to `#8` are used to refer to various components of a person's name. The odd numbers give the full string, whereas even numbers abbreviate this to just initials. Here they are. In brackets I've added what they'd be if my name was `Richard Wayne "Dick" van Dyke Senior`.

- `#1` and `#2`: Surname(s), aka family names (`Dyke`, or `D.`)
- `#3` and `#4`: First and middle name(s), aka given names (``` Richard Wayne ``Dick'' ```)
- `#5` and `#6`: Any name prefixes (`van`)
- `#7` and `#8`: Any name suffixes, aka affixes (`Senior`)

More recent versions of biblatex don't pass this information around as positional arguments; instead they're available as named macros. (This certainly makes it easier for a novice to understand what the format is actually doing. Here's what the arguments numbers above need to be translated into. Notice that the abbreviated versions are the same macro with an `i` at the end.

- `\namepartfamily` and `\namepartfamilyi`
- `\namepartgiven`  and `\namepartgiveni`
- `\namepartprefix` and `\namepartprefixi`
- `\namepartsuffix` and `\namepartsuffixi`

If we replace all instances of `#1` through `#8` in this way, we get a document that compiles happily with bold surnames in the bibliography.
However, biblatex isn't completely happy with us.

```
Package biblatex Warning: '\iffirstinits' is deprecated, use '\ifgiveninits'.
Package biblatex Warning: 'name:first-last' is deprecated, please use 'name:given-family'.
```

I guess the change in terminology is to better support names where the family comes first, e.g. with Japanese names.
After updating the macro and strings as requested, the MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last-bold}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero,wilde,baez/article,knuth:ct,aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output from LaTeX is just as in moewe's answer.