# Make author names bold in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I want the authors' and  the year bibliography to be bold and the second line to be indented. please guide me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}
text \cite{1} \cite{1}


\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

reference:

```
[![@book{1,
title={Vibrations of soils and foundations},
author={E Richart, F},
year={1970},
publisher={Printed in the United States of America}
}
@article{5,
title={On the partition of energy between elastic waves in a semi-infinite solid},
author={Miller, GF and Pursey, H and Bullard, Edward Crisp},
journal={Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A. Mathematical and Physical Sciences},
volume={233},
number={1192},
pages={55--69},
year={1955},
publisher={The Royal Society London}
}
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows both the authors *and* the year in bold; in contrast, your posting suggests that you want just the authors' names in bold. Please clarify.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The `plain` bibliography style places the year at the end. Do you still want the year field to be placed at the end even when it's rendered in **bold**?

Comment: No, next year will be the authors for all reference.

Comment: Then *why* did you specify that you use the `plain` bibliography style? Please clarify what you really need to achieve, and please state which bibliography style you need to employ. Please also clarify whether you need to generate authoryear-style or numeric-style citation call-outs?

Comment: I need a style that looks like the picture.It is not necessary to use plain style.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any bibliography style that "looks like the picture" you posted. Sorry.

Comment: I think you should familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package. The utility walks you through a series of questions, each with multiple-choice answers (one of which is the default or null answer). At the end of the questionnaire, it'll create a bespoke bst file that'll satisfy all of your bibliography-related formatting requirements. Open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst` to get going.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know much English. Explained in the address https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178862/make-author-names-bold-in-bibliography-only but I could not run.

Comment: The link you provided points to a style file which places the year field at the very end of each bibliographic entry. Moreover, that bibliography style uses the keyword `and` rather than commas as the separator between authors. Didn't you declare earlier that you "need a style that looks like the picture" you posted in your query? All I can suggest at this point is that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.