# Use short form with \cite

Tags: biblatex

I am using a modified `verbose-ibid` citestyle (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178555/51451)). If I use `\cite`, it won't use the short version, and that might be good, but right know I need to use the short version (`cite:short`). So how would I use `\cite` and force the short form?

Comment: It should "just work" (i.e. citations after the first should be shortened) unless you have set the option `citetracker=false` ... or unless you have made some other modifications. Try setting `citetracker=true` explicitly. Or do you want *all* citations short, even the first?

Comment: @PaulStanley Sadly, it doesn't. I forgot to mention that I am using `\cite` within an image `\caption`, could that cause the problem?

Comment: As far as I know citetrackers are disabled in floats, so that might indeed be the problem. The `biblatex` documentation states: "To avoid any such ambiguities, the citation and page trackers are temporarily disabled in all floats." (§4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF*, p. 232 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Comment: @moewe wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I have added an answer (better late than never, I presume).

Answer (score 4):

Since captions (and floats in general) are rarely considered part of the text flow (after all a float is quite volatile in its placement and it is even more difficult to predict when exactly a reader might look at a float), the trackers are disabled within those environments.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states in §4.11.5 Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF, p. 232

> If a citation is given in a float (typically in the caption of a
>   figure or table), scholarly back references like ‘ibidem’ or back
>   references based on the page tracker get am- biguous because floats
>   are objects which are (physically and logically) placed outside the
>   flow of text, hence the logic of such references applies poorly to
>   them. To avoid any such ambiguities, the citation and page trackers
>   are temporarily disabled in all floats. In addition to that, these
>   trackers plus the back reference tracker (`backref`) are temporarily
>   disabled in the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list
>   of tables.

So this behaviour is indeed intended, if you want to force short citations instead, you can define an "enforcer"

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captshort}{\let\blx@imc@ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}
\makeatother
```

If you use this within a caption (e.g. `\caption{\captshort\cite{foo}}`), short citations will be forced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captshort}{\let\blx@imc@ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \cite{geer} \cite{geer}

  \begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{\captshort\cite{geer}}
  \end{table}

  \cite{wilde} \cite{wilde}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1: Geer, “Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music”]

---

Alternatively, we can define a new cite command `\shrtcite` that always prints the short form and use that instead

```
\newbibmacro*{shrtcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\shrtcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{shrtcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{shrtcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\shrtcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{shrtcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{geer} \cite{geer}

  \begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{\shrtcite{geer}}
  \end{table}

  \cite{wilde} \cite{wilde}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1: Geer, “Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music”]