# Citations in text and table, show the first author name from the second citation?

Tags: tables, biblatex, citing, apa-style

there are some citations **with three or more authors** in text, I want to collect these citations in a table now. In the text, all author names will be printed when first cited, and only the first author name will be printed from the second citation. It works well in text, but it is not when I put them in a table. The code below shows what I mean (Note: apa style is used):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC:2014,
  author = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B. and AuthorC, C},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Paper1},
}
@misc{ABC:2016,
  author = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B. and AuthorC, C},
  year = {2016},
  title = Paper2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text \autocite{ABC:2014}.\\
Some text \autocite{ABC:2016}.

\noindent
Some text \cite{ABC:2014}.\\
Some text \cite{ABC:2016}.

\noindent
Some text \textcite{ABC:2014}.\\
Some text \textcite{ABC:2016}.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{example}
\begin{tabular}{llll} 
\hline
colum1 & column2 & column3 & \cite{ABC:2014} \\
colum1 & column2 & column3 & \cite{ABC:2016} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It will show the result as the attached figure. I suppose the citations in the table will be the form "first author name + et al.", but it is not.
The intelligent way I can figure out is use "\cite*{ABC:2014} \citeyear{ABC:2014}" instead of the standard command "\cite" or "\textcite". However, this does not solve my problem well, as **I want it show all names if there are two authors**. Is there a better way to achieve this?
Thanks!
[image: The citation in the table does follow these in text]

Comment: Does `\citeauthor*{<key>}` work in `biblatex-apa`? Could be a temporary workaround....

Comment: thanks. \citeauthor*{} will just listt the first author, which is not fit for a citation with only two authors.

Comment: AFAIK, `biblatex-apa` checks if an item has been cited before and goes to the short citation only then. But in floats (tables, for example), this check is disabled and always yields false, that is because floats are in a way independent of the text flow.

Comment: See [\footcite always prints long citation if used in `figure` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252723/35864) and [Use short form with \cite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180649/35864). The solution from the first link works here as well.