# Automatic citation in list of figures

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, floats, citing

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` as backend. I want to create citations for my figures by using a `\cite` command, but surpress any output of it in the caption of a figure or in the footnotes of the respective page.

Instead the citation (including a page number) should be printed only in the `\listoffigures`, ideally instead of the caption. I'm using the style `verbose-ibid`. I'd like the references in the list of figures to be printed in the abbreviated form of that style by default. The cited book should be added to the bibliography as well, if it wasn't cited before in the text.

What I'm doing so far:

Placing the `\cite` command inside `[]` of `\caption[]{}` to avoid any output of the citation on the page of the figure and to print the citation inside the list of figures. The cited book gets also added to the bibliography.

Everythings just fine except for the citation style inside the list of figures (always prints full citation).

Any ideas how to achieve the abbreviated citation style in list of figures by default? Is there an overall better approach to this than mine?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@Book{knuth1986,
    Title                    = {The \TeX book},
    Author                   = {Donald~Ervin Knuth},
    Publisher                = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year                     = {1986}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption[{\cite[][5]{knuth1986}}]{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please ask a new question about the issue with the bold names? I can explain why it goes wrong, but since the original question got answered (and is a duplicate) that makes admin a bit easier.

Comment: I'm going to remove the edit and make a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @moewe I posted the new [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541742/why-are-citations-in-listoffigures-printing-the-label-of-the-bib-entry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code for short citations from Moewe's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236894/29873

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\newbibmacro*{shrtcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\shrtcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{shrtcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}


\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@Book{knuth1986,
    Title                    = {The \TeX book},
    Author                   = {Donald~Ervin Knuth},
    Publisher                = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year                     = {1986}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption[{\shrtcite[][5]{knuth1986}}]{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my post, describing the problems I still encounter.

Comment: Are you using Moewe's code? Is this a new issue? If so, please ask a new question.